# Upgrading 1.7 to 1.9 using old database. throws an error

Tags: magento-1.9

Upgrading 1.7 to 1.9 using old database. throwing an error
**I am not able to add the products to the cart and also not able to edit products from admin side**.

```
 Exception message: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'rule.calculate_subtotal' in 'field list', query was: SELECT `main_table`.`tax_calculation_rate_id`, `main_table`.`tax_calculation_rule_id`, `main_table`.`customer_tax_class_id`, `main_table`.`product_tax_class_id`, `rule`.`priority`, `rule`.`position`, `rule`.`calculate_subtotal`, `rate`.`rate` AS `value`, `rate`.`tax_country_id`, `rate`.`tax_region_id`, `rate`.`tax_postcode`, `rate`.`tax_calculation_rate_id`, `rate`.`code`, IF(title_table.value IS NULL, rate.code, title_table.value) AS `title` FROM `tax_calculation` AS `main_table`
INNER JOIN `tax_calculation_rule` AS `rule` ON `rule`.`tax_calculation_rule_id` = main_table.tax_calculation_rule_id
INNER JOIN `tax_calculation_rate` AS `rate` ON rate.tax_calculation_rate_id = main_table.tax_calculation_rate_id
LEFT JOIN `tax_calculation_rate_title` AS `title_table` ON rate.tax_calculation_rate_id = title_table.tax_calculation_rate_id AND title_table.store_id = '1' WHERE (customer_tax_class_id = 3) AND (product_tax_class_id IN ('2')) AND (rate.tax_country_id = 'US') AND (rate.tax_region_id IN(0, 12)) AND (rate.zip_is_range IS NULL) ORDER BY `priority` ASC, `tax_calculation_rule_id` ASC, `tax_country_id` DESC, `tax_region_id` DESC, `tax_postcode` DESC, `value` DESC
Trace: #0 lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#4 /lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#5 /lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(737): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
#6 /app/code/core/Mage/Tax/Model/Resource/Calculation.php(358): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchAll(Object(Varien_Db_Select))
#7 /app/code/core/Mage/Tax/Model/Resource/Calculation.php(99): Mage_Tax_Model_Resource_Calculation->_getRates(Object(Varien_Object))
#8 /home/exdev/domains/exinentdev.tqhosting.com/public_html/innov8tivedesign/app/code/core/Mage/Tax/Model/Calculation.php(282): Mage_Tax_Model_Resource_Calculation->getRateInfo(Object(Varien_Object))
#9 app/code/core/Mage/Tax/Model/Sales/Total/Quote/Subtotal.php(512): Mage_Tax_Model_Calculation->getRate(Object(Varien_Object))
#10 design/app/code/core/Mage/Tax/Model/Sales/Total/Quote/Subtotal.php(210): Mage_Tax_Model_Sales_Total_Quote_Subtotal->_totalBaseCalculation(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item), Object(Varien_Object))
#11 design/app/code/core/Mage/Tax/Model/Sales/Total/Quote/Subtotal.php(184): Mage_Tax_Model_Sales_Total_Quote_Subtotal->_processItem(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item), Object(Varien_Object))
#12 design/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Address.php(1013): Mage_Tax_Model_Sales_Total_Quote_Subtotal->collect(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address))
#13 /app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php(1331): Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address->collectTotals()
#14 app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Cart.php(458): Mage_Sales_Model_Quote->collectTotals()
#15 app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php(228): Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart->save()
#16 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Checkout_CartController->addAction()
#17 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('add')
#18 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#19 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#20 app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#21 public_html/magento-instance/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#22 {main}
```

Comment: Please provide some more context. Cutting off the error message in the middle certainly doesn't help either.

Comment: I just updated my query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The column `calculate_subtotal` has been added in Magento 1.8. It looks like the Magento upgrade scripts did not run successfully.

Comment: I created the column calculate_subtotal using phpmyadmin in tax_calculation_rule manually. is that correct way ??